# How to make "Never Ending Service" in android? I'm using Xiomi and vivo and in these device service is being killed while removing it from recents?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm using xiomi and vivo device and while removing app from recents in both the device service is being killed and not restarting as I had used receiver.
I had also used startForeground for OREO+ version but still its not working in xiomi and vivo phones. So I just want to create a service which just print log at every seconds and it should continue even if user remove it from recents.
Thank you in advance.

Till now I had tried this code shown below:

```
public class SensorService extends Service {
    public int counter=0;
    public SensorService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        Log.i("HERE", "here I am!");
    }

    public SensorService() {
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("EXIT_destroy", "ondestroy!");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        stoptimertask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.i("EXIT_taskRemoved", "ondestroy!");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        stoptimertask();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    long oldTime=0;
    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
    }

    /**
     * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
     */
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("in timer", "in timer ++++  "+ (counter++));
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * not needed
     */
    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Its not working in xiomi and vivo devices while removing it from recents

Comment: This is not exactly a direct solution, but I think it's relevant so I'll leave it here: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Services always run in main thread, you should implement your service in another Thread. Just use `IntentService` instead of `Service`.

Comment: How you binded service? If you used onBind() then service stops when you do not have any activities connected to it. If you use onStartCommand() to start service then it will run even if noone does any job, but you should stop that services using stopSelf() or stopService().